# Why my IF statement is not working?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, if-statement, ksh

My if statement is not working as it should and I do not get why.

This is what I have

```
for LINE in $(cat someFile.txt)
do
inst=$(echo $LINE | awk -F, '{print $4}')
echo $inst  # To verify is displaying correctly
if [ $inst == "UP" ]
then
    echo "Program skips this when $inst is UP"
elif [ $inst == "DN" ]
then
    echo "Program skips this when $inst is DN"
fi
done
```

And when I use `-eq` for the IF statement, the program displays this `UP^M: 0403-009 The specified number is not valid for this command.`

Any ideas??

---

EDIT. FOUND THE ANSWER:

For some reason the program is adding a return character at the end.

Adding this: `inst=$(echo $inst | tr -d '\r')` right after getting the column value resolves the issue.

Comment: Did you transfert your script from a window machine to a unix one ? In that case, `dos2unix your_script_file` might help you.

Comment: What does it display, and what do you expect it to display?

Comment: @LucM: No, did not transfer it from a Windows Machine

Comment: @beny23: The program was adding a return character at the end of the line, that is why it was never "UP" or "DN" exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND THE ANSWER:

For some reason the program is adding a return character at the end.

Adding this: `inst=$(echo $inst | tr -d '\r')` right after getting the column value resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

dos2 unix on the source file might help too, the someFile.txt

Comment: I'm actually creating the someFile.txt within the program, "someFile.txt" was just an example. It's creating actually a CSV file